Prometheus update - reoccuring every day
After reboot, snapstore shows a notification, that a software update has been successfully installed ("Prometheus"). When I open snap-store it shows the update with a warning, that the system cant be used while updating (see screenshot). I do not know what "Prometheus" actually is, whether I do need it, and why the update information keeps showing up.
I have an ubuntu 24.04 (desktop - no server).
I appreciate any hints. Thanks

This is an English only site so a picture of non English text does not help.

I have the same problem on my Ubuntu. The message in Ubuntu with en-us locale says "Device cannot be used during update."

Prometheus is a firmware for fingerprint reader devices. For example, the one on a Levono Thinkpad laptop.
The update notice could occur on every startup if the firmeware updater sees that your Prometheus' current version (e.g. 10.01.4xxxx) is even newer (larger) than the "latest" version (e.g. 10.01.3478575) that the firmware updater can see from its list.
To work around it (i.e. make the update notice disappear), press left Super key to "Show Apps", and open "Firmware Updater". In the left sidebar of Firmware Updater, find Prometheus. Try downgrading the firmware to the "latest" one  (e.g. 10.01.3478575) that the updater can see from its list.
